# Prepared statements possible when mysqli and PDO are not available?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

Are PHP/mysql prepared statements possible when mysqli and PDO are not available?  Are there working Pear solutions for this problem?

Comment: Technically, yes, you can write your own mysql-connecting library in PHP, but unless you want to a couple of full time weeks on the project and even then find little nasty bugs everywhere, it just isn't practical. There are enough libs the _'emulate'_ prepares, but they are just sending raw queries just the same. _Why_ are PDO and/or mysqli not available? Ancient PHP version?

Comment: There is an emulation for PDO targetted at PHP4, so technically usable also when PDO is compiled out. See xpdo.org or upgradephp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.intro-execute.php

That should contain all the information you need.

Otherwise, the standard mysql_* functions do not provide functionality for prepared statements.

Comment: These aren't actual prepares / binds, see the [introduction](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.intro.php):" _Prepare/execute (bind) **emulation**_ Then again, it might be suitable for the OP if he doesn't need actual prepares.

Comment: @Wrikken: Afaik, MDB2 executes [actual prepared statements in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html). It doesn't emulate them.

Comment: Hm, hey, this seems, new (`./Driver/mysql.php:917`), well, I stand corrected. Still manual client-side escaping, but a bigger plus nonetheless, thanks @netcoder.